# android HTTP post request returns bad error

Tags: javascript, android, http-post

I am trying to hit a URL. The server end is a java script as below

```
function interact(message){
// loading message
$('<div class="message loading new"><figure class="avatar"><img 
src="/static/res/im.png" /></figure><span></span>
</div>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container'));
// make a POST request [ajax ]
$.post('/message', {
    msg: message,
}).done(function(reply) {


$('.message.loading').remove();

$('<div class="message new"><figure class="avatar"><img src="/static/res/botim.png" /></figure>' + reply['text'] + '</div>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container')).addClass('new');
setDate();
updateScrollbar();
```

I am calling this through http android client

```
    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.28.2.1:5000/message");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The URL is hit but its showing bad request

```
"POST /message HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Comment: message is a file or what...?

Comment: not a file... actually that js code is for a website with chat interface .. when i hit url 'http //10.28.2.1:5000' in browser it gives a text box ... where you type in messages and send.

Answer (score 0):

`10.28.2.1:5000` is your local server? If yes -  download and install [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and run in console `ngrok http 5000` . You got a link, than you connect to your local server from any device with url from console (just like `miekka12kupa.ngrok.io` (it will be written in console). Use this URL to connect from android device